# Understanding degrees of freedom of F-statistic in Linear Regression

Tags: regression, linear-model, degrees-of-freedom, f-test

I was reviewing linear regression and I wanted to dig deeper into the F test that many software suites provide. I am aware that many sources comment on the degrees of freedom, but I haven't really found an answer that satisfies me.

I've been taught that if we take two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, both following chi-squared distributions with $n_1$ and $n_2$ degrees of freedom, than we have that:
$$
F = \frac{\frac{X_1}{n_1}}{\frac{X_2}{n_2}} \sim F(n_1, n_2)
$$

The way I understand this is that this is helpful because F can be now seen as the fraction of two variances, given that the variance is computed as sum of squared differences ($\sim \chi^2(n)$, assuming that the residuals follow a Z-distribution) divided by $n$.
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n{(y_i - \mu)^2}}{n} \rightarrow \frac{X}{n} \quad \text{where} \quad X \sim \chi^2(n)
$$

However, when reviewing linear regression, I stumbled upon another statistic that is said to follow a F-distribution:
$$
F = \frac{\frac{SS_{mean} - SS_{fit}}{p_{fit} - p_{mean}}}{\frac{SS_{fit}}{n - p_{fit}}} = \frac{\frac{S_1}{d_1}}{\frac{S_2}{d_2}}\sim F(d_1, d_2)
$$

Now, if I understood the F-distribution correctly, $S_1 = SS_{mean} - SS_{fit}$ should have $d_1$ degrees of freedom and follow a $\chi^2(d_1)$. Similarly, $S_2 = SS_{fit} \sim \chi^2(d_2)$.

The problem is that I can't wrap my head around this:

- why $SS_{fit}$ has $n - p_{fit}$ degrees of freedom? I mean, does it really have those degrees of freedom or we simply adjust the formula like so arbitrarily? For me, since we're talking about a sum of squares, the degrees of freedom are always given by the "size" of the sum ($n$), because we sum $n$ Z-distributed variables. Why is it not the case?
  $$
  SS_{fit} = \sum_{i=0}^n{(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2} \sim \chi^2(n)
  $$
- why $SS_{mean} - SS_{fit}$ has $p_{fit} - p_{mean}$ degrees of freedom? In this case, given that it is a difference, I can't really have an intuition for which should be the degrees of freedom.

Any help is greatly appreciated.